# FTP server connection is refused when connecting through VPN

Tags: windows-7, vpn, ftp

I'm trying to connect from my laptop with Windows 7 to a server running Windows (I don't know the version). The VPN connection is established by the Cisco AnyConnect client.

I need to modify files on the server directly and not by remote desktop. I'm trying to connect via FTP but the log says:

> connection refused by server

Comment: Your question is very vague. From where are you connecting, to where? What OSes are involved? How did you set up the VPN? Did you set it up yourself? Is the server out of your control? Did you set the routes properly?

Comment: I've fixed the post

Comment: And do you know that the remote machine runs an FTP server? Like, can you connect to it from the company network?

Comment: I don't know if remote machine runs an ftp server, is there a way to discover it ?It is the first time I try to connect it from home and it is the only way

Comment: You need to ask the system administrator. I'm sorry, but this question is impossible to answer otherwise, because there could be a server running and you're just blocked through a firewall, or there is no server at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible to do.

You need to make sure the server is running an FTP server, and that there is no firewall preventing you from accessing it.

Comment: Ok thank you. And if I try to use windows 7 function (connect network unit) I need some authorization from server or firewall?

Comment: @StefanoMaglione port 21/TCP is used for FTP. make sure it is forwarded by the router and allowed through firewall. tip: consider adding the exception only to the desired IP range.